# What is wrong with this google sheets formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to use this formula in google sheets:

```
=QUERY({sheet1!A2:D;sheet2!A2:D},"select * where Col4>=65 order by Col4 desc")
```

but I get "Formula parse error" basically I want to get data from multiple sheets tabs and display it into one sheet but I want the data to be sorted and only get results where Col4 is >= to 65 or even better it would be to only display the top 3 results from each tab

I tried that by using

```
=sortn({sheet1!A2:D;sheet2!A2:D};5;0;4;0)
```

but this display top 5 results from both tabs overall but I would like if I could get top 3 results from each tab.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a programming problem. It might be suitable for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Quentin there are [8013 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-formula) asked regarding google sheets formula. I don't think it should be closed for this reason.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it.  I can create two sheets, plop in some data, cut and paste your formula into a third sheet and get success.  If I play with the data on the first two sheets and get rid of some columns or whatnot to make it so that it's not pointing to real data, then I do get some errors.  But never a parse error.

Comment: @pwilcox thanks for the reply but i figured what actually gave me the parse error, it's the ' , "select... ' the , in it after I changed it to ; it worked than my question is can I change that query to give 3 result from each tab ? because if I use Limit 3 ... same thing as on sortn. i really wonder if it's possible to limit the results in a way to get only N no. from each tab

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try a custom function ?

```js
function filterDataBiggerThen(rangeA1, column, value, limit) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let output = [];
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => sh.getName() !== activeSheet.getName())
    .map(sh => sh.getRange(rangeA1).getValues().sort((a, b) => b[column - 1] - a[column - 1])
      .forEach((row, i) => {
        if (row[column - 1] >= value && i < limit) output.push(row)
      })
    )
  return output && output.length ? output : "No data found";
}
```

In your spreadsheet you can use this function as a formula

```
=filterDataBiggerThen("A2:D"; 4; 65; 3)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, this looks promising just one question how do I apply this to multiple sheet tabs ? because I have to pull data from multiple tabs into 1. And I just tested it but it seems there is some problems if I use it as it is I get 3 data displayed but twice. I get 6 results back the top 3 repeated and if i try to use range from 2 sheets i get an error "range not found (line 6)"

Comment: The script will get ALL the abs except for the active sheet (where the formula is entered).  For the other issues... it would be very helpful if you could share a copy of your spreadsheet (any sensitive data erased) so I can have a closer look.

Comment: Ok my mistake i see that it gets data from all tabs , but the problem  it's that I want all the data pulled to be ordered by Col4, and not sure why but it takes awhile for the data to load :P btw copy : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13LJuW-P3FFAqqoxzeTS6MGDvLQTisL6dpId_DrQiES0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ohh and i just found another problem, if I delete data from a sheet or change the data, the data on the active sheet doesn't update unless I refresh the page but if I do that don't know why the result move down with 3 rows(i put the formula in A2 but it moved to A5 and after that if I change the data on the other sheets again .. and refresh it doesn't even update anymore

Answer (score 0):

Well hello, after much trial and error I managed to get a formula that does exactly what I want there is just one simple problem it's so long .... but maybe it can help others too or someone can come up with a way to simplify it.

```
=SORT(IFERROR({iferror(query({sheet1!A2:D}; "select * where Col4>=65 order by Col4 desc Limit 3";0);A2:D2/0); iferror(query({sheet2!A2:D}; "select * where Col4>=65 order by Col4 desc Limit 3";0);A2:D2/0)});4;0)
```

This formula will display 3 results from each tab like I wanted and will sort it overall all the data displayed but like I said it's very long already and if I want to add more tabs it will get even longer. But it's the only solution I could come up with that does everything I needed automatically. I hope it can help people and if there is someone who can simplify it that would be an even greater help.